# nested loop optimization

Tags: c#, sql, optimization, nested

Hi all I have a weird optimization question, here is the code I have changed some names for simplicity

```
CollectionObject mycollobj = new CollectionObject();
List<string> MyProducts = new List<string>();
//get collection of selected customers that were passed in
var chckedValues = form.GetValues("assignChkBx");
foreach(string customer in chckedValues )
{
    MyProducts.Clear();
    //MyProducts is then set to a data access method in my data access class
    MyProducts = DataLayerClass.GetProductsFromCustomer(customer);
    foreach(string product in MyProducts)
    {
       string item1 = DataLayerClass.GetItem1(product);
       string item2 = DataLayerClass.GetItem2(product);
       mycollobj.loaditems(item1, item2);
    }
}
```

Essentially mycollobj is a black box that is used for some fairly involved analysis (that I have no control over).  Is there any better way to run this nested algorithm?  Any suggestions are valued and please ask if you need clarification on anything.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI this all works, its just slow

Comment: If `mycollobj.loaditems` is the slow part, can you move that call to a background thread?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what is slow, the whole process is slow (still a beginner at this stuff)

Comment: How is the DataLayerClass implemented?  Specifically, when does it actually retrieve the data from the database?

Comment: Tried profiling to see what's slow?

Comment: The DataLayerClass is a static class that uses string methods that return values from stored procs.  That help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this line: `MyProducts = DataLayerClass.GetProductsFromCustomer(customer);` is going to slow things down (a database call for every customer), also the nested `DataLayerClass.GetItem1()/GetItem2` is making things much worse. Rather send down all the `checkedValues` to the database and return a Lookup with the customer and a `Tuple` containing `item1` and `item2`:

```
ILookup<Customer, Tuple<string, string>> customerProducts = 
 DataLayerClass.GetCustomersWithProducts(chckedValues);
```

In short terms, move the logic to a single database query.

Comment: I'm not sure where this would go in the code, do we nest it inside the first loop?

Comment: also there is no customer object, so I am a bit confused

Comment: No this would be done outside any loop. And than loop the result to call `mycollobj.loaditems(item1, item2);`